# How do you access shared realms?

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've been working with realm db in a React Native App for the last couple of days.
I'm wondering how to implement sharing of realms: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#permissionofferpermissionresponse

I understand that you have to create a permission offer and then send it to the specified user. Then that user accepts the offer and he is granted access to this realm. What I have difficulties understanding is - how do I know what realms a user has access to? Where do I keep this - I can't find information about the shared realms in the managementRealm object. Am I supposed to keep track of the realms a user has access to myself?

We have the following structure:
company -> field -> comments

Each user of the App is able to create companies & to share those companies with other users. Upon start of the App the user sees the companies he has access to:

- Company 1
- Company 2

Each company is a realm (database). Do I need a special realm (e.g. company_track) to keep track of realms that a user has created and has been granted access to? 
So when the app starts I would provide the url to the company_track realm and from there I would read the data necessary to load the other realms.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with Realm, but not with the permissions stuff, I can't say this for certain, but it seems each user's management realm should contain permission objects representing all the realms they can access.

After reading a bit on the [Xamarin docs](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#modifying-permissions), it says that the management realm is supposed to hold an object of type [`Permission`](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/api/reference/Realms.Sync.Permission.html) for each realm the user has access to. The permission object contains the url to the realm and the access levels a user has.

There should be [something similar](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/1.10.0/api/PermissionChange.html) for use in javascript as the underlying tech is the same.

Comment: Interesting. User.openManagemetnRealm() gives me the management realm. On javascript this realm object doesn't seem to contain a Permission schema/object. I only have permissionChange, permissionOffer, permissionOfferResponse

Comment: Might it be that permission change object contains the effective permissions?